# can I use variables defined in foundation's scss in my application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

In my rails application's asset `application.css` I have the following line

```
/*
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

ul#mainmenu li {
    background-color: $mainColor;
}
```

which includes the file `foundation_and_overrides.scss` where I defined the following variable

```
$mainColor: #eba10e;
```

But when I now try to use this variable directly in my `application.css` file, it is not translated to `#eba10e`, so I get lines like this one in the resulting css file:

```
background-color: $mainColor;
```

So my question, **how can I use the variable in my application.css file?**

Comment: Did you require foundation_and_overrides *before* you require self?

Comment: @MarlinPierce Yes. I updated the snippet in the question. As you see, the require_self is after foundation_and_overrides. I guess the problem is the extension because when I rename the file to `.scss` I get an error telling me that the variable `$mainColor` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pure CSS does not support variables.

But it will work, if you rename it to `application.scss`. After that it will be compiled with Sass. CSS is always valid SCSS, so this will work without problems.

Additionally you have to use the `@import` statement instead of `require`, so the other files will be imported the ”SASS way“.

Comment: Thanks, but when I rename it to `.scss` I get the following error: `Undefined variable: "$mainColor".`...

Comment: My fault, additionally you have to use the `@import` statement instead of `require`.

Comment: Uhmm... and what's with `require_tree .` and `require_self`? I guess `require_self` is not needed anymore but `require_tree`?